# Moving 100.000+ files in Node.js sync / async performance and speed

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, asynchronous, node-async

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way without affecting performance much while moving either synchronously or asynchronously 100.000+ files using Node.js

I made sync and async tests with 3 different looping `forEach` `async.each` and `for`. The loop iterations didn't impact timing results much. And the heaviest logic affecting performance and speed is moving files either synchronously or asynchronously.

The test cases showed, that synchronous `renameSync()` is slower at 20% then asynchronous `rename()`. In the same time asynchronous `rename()` using 3 times more CPU power, then synchronous `renameSync()`.

---

Am I right to assume that it would be wiser to use synchronous `renameSync()` because speed boost in asynchronous `rename()` is not so significant and equal to 20%. While CPU utilization overhead in async version seems to be huge - 300%?

Or did I miss anything? Maybe there are better workarounds in terms of speed/performance.

> The timings:

```
eachAsyncRenameAsync()

node rename.js  1.60s user 11.20s system 280% cpu 4.559 total
node rename.js  1.65s user 11.82s system 284% cpu 4.732 total
node rename.js  1.64s user 11.84s system 292% cpu 4.606 total


eachSyncRenameSync()

node rename.js  0.69s user 5.01s system 97% cpu 5.851 total
node rename.js  0.67s user 4.88s system 97% cpu 5.687 total
node rename.js  0.68s user 5.01s system 99% cpu 5.734 total


eachAsyncRenameSync()

node rename.js  0.67s user 4.99s system 97% cpu 5.797 total
node rename.js  0.68s user 4.95s system 97% cpu 5.754 total
node rename.js  0.66s user 4.89s system 97% cpu 5.690 total


eachSyncRenameAsync()

node rename.js  1.63s user 11.12s system 274% cpu 4.638 total
node rename.js  1.66s user 12.29s system 286% cpu 4.874 total
node rename.js  1.66s user 12.23s system 289% cpu 4.795 total


forSyncRenameAsync()

node rename.js  1.72s user 12.04s system 283% cpu 4.862 total
node rename.js  1.69s user 11.88s system 276% cpu 4.904 total
node rename.js  1.64s user 11.89s system 287% cpu 4.712 total


forSyncRenameSync()

node rename.js  0.64s user 4.94s system 97% cpu 5.715 total
node rename.js  0.66s user 5.01s system 97% cpu 5.807 total
node rename.js  0.65s user 4.93s system 99% cpu 5.616 total
```

> The code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const { each } = require('async')

let dir = '/opt/bin/test/Random 100000'
let dir2 = '/opt/bin/test/Random 100000 2'

function eachAsyncRenameAsync(files) {
        each(files, file => {
              fs.rename(path.join(dir,file), path.join(dir2,file), err => {
                if(err) { console.log(err) }
              })
        })
}

function eachSyncRenameSync(files) {
    files.forEach(file => {
            fs.renameSync(path.join(dir,file), path.join(dir2,file))
    })
}

function eachAsyncRenameSync(files) {
    each(files, file => {
            fs.renameSync(path.join(dir,file), path.join(dir2,file))
    })
}

function eachSyncRenameAsync(files) {
    files.forEach(file => {
        fs.rename(path.join(dir,file), path.join(dir2,file), err => {
                if(err) { console.log(err) }
        })
    })
}

function forSyncRenameAsync(files) {
    for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        fs.rename(path.join(dir, files[i]), path.join(dir2, files[i]), err => {
                if(err) { console.log(err) }
        })
    }

}

function forSyncRenameSync(files) {
    for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        fs.renameSync(path.join(dir, files[i]), path.join(dir2, files[i]))
    }
}

// Reading dir asynchronously and moving files

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }
    else {
        console.log('eachAsyncRenameAsync()')
        eachAsyncRenameAsync(files)
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

for asynchronous performans comparison-optimization,making a pool to limit the number of concurrent operations will let you find the optimal result.

the benchmark you made shows that the optimal result is between 1 and n async concurent operations.

Comment: I don't think this is the place to explain mathematical theories... My answer needs more explanation for those who is not familiar with math... I don't think that kind of explanation is what i should make here... 

Still , using  pool(s)  to deal with over using async callbacks , and making the best optimizations for the jobs , will result the best . Here , n  is the number of async concurent operations. My answer is clear enough for especially nodejs programmers , who already deal with callbacks.

Comment: ---- How does this answer OP's question?---

It does not solve it. it is the explanationof the result of the bench .
What would you expect ? generate a pool library as an answer doing the whole job optimally ?
----

Comment: other commenter gone , just leaving those comments for someone not to repeat that behaviour. thank you.

Comment: "it is the explanationof the result of the bench" - but it doesn't explain anything either.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica , why don't you let the op to see the solution, although this is an old question, the problem is a general case , which many of us nodejs developers face. This , what you are trying to do is just so offensive. Using pooling method , is already suggested in official documentary of NodeJS. The implementation is optimal , for just the target platform , and using pooling is not any difficult . The answer which i wrote , is clearly helpful for anyone, was a solution for me , and will be a solution for many if you let it.

Comment: there are some good pooling libraries. @user2357112supportsMonica , you can google it and use pooling in your code if you need to .